# Parsing SQL 'between' and 'and' expressions with ANTLR 4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have difficulties with a SQL expression parser. Specifically, with the `a AND b` and `a BETWEEN c AND d` rules. The alternatives are specified as follows:

```
| lhs=exprRule K_AND rhs=exprRule  # AndExpression
| value=exprRule K_NOT? K_BETWEEN lower=exprRule K_AND upper=exprRule  # BetweenExpression
```

Unfortunately, this grammar parses a string, such as

```
...
l_discount BETWEEN 0.02 - 0.01 AND 0.02 + 0.01 
AND l_quantity < 25
...
```

as `BetweenExpression` with `lower={0.02 - 0.01 AND 0.02 + 0.01}` and `upper={l_quantity < 25}`. Clearly, I want it to be parsed as `lower={0.02 - 0.01}` and `upper={0.02 + 0.01}` with an `AndExpression` as parent node.

Basically, I want the `lower=exprRule` of the `BetweenExpression` to take the smallest number of tokens instead of the largest number. It seems to me that there should be a straightforward solution to this but I lack the nomenclature to phrase the correct google search and could not find an answer in the ANTLR documantation either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tried, as suggest by mnesarco, to give `BETWEEN` expressions alt a higher precedence, but in both cases, the parse tree:

[image]

is created. Which makes sense if you think about it.

The only thing I could come up with is the introduce an extra "numeric expression" rule that does not match `and` and `between` expressions:

```
exprRule
 : value=exprRule ( '+' | '-' ) lower=exprRule                                #AddExpression
 | value=exprRule ( '<' | '>' | '<=' | '=>' ) lower=exprRule                  #ComparisonExpression
 | value=exprRule K_NOT? K_BETWEEN lower=exprNumeric K_AND upper=exprNumeric  #BetweenExpression
 | lhs=exprRule K_AND rhs=exprRule                                            #AndExpression
 | NUMBER                                                                     #NumberExpression
 | ID                                                                         #IdExpression
 ;

exprNumeric
 : value=exprNumeric ( '+' | '-' ) lower=exprNumeric  #AddNumericExpression
 | NUMBER                                             #NumNumericberExpression
 | ID                                                 #IdNumericExpression
 ;
```

which results in the parse tree:

[image]

Comment: I believe you are correct. I found a T-SQL grammar that splits conditional and simple expressions into separate rules (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/tsql/TSqlParser.g4). The same repository also holds a SQLite grammar, which I used as starting point for my own solution, but that does not seem to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a precedence problem. basically you need [Between] operator to have higher precedence than [And] and probably than [Or] too.

In Antlr4, precedence is just order of definition. So just try swapping the alternative order. ie:

```
| value=exprRule K_NOT? K_BETWEEN lower=exprRule K_AND upper=exprRule  # BetweenExpression
| lhs=exprRule K_AND rhs=exprRule  # AndExpression
```

Comment: I also tried this, but it does not work. The `lower=exprRule` still consumes `0.02 - 0.01 AND 0.02 + 0.01` and `upper=exprRule` takes the rest: `l_quantity < 25` regardless what alternative is placed first.

Comment: It is hard to analyze without the complete grammar.

Comment: I created a small test grammar that exhibited what I just described.